# Why am I getting this error when trying to upload a file in Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have made a small project which takes a csv file and uploads it. it then processes its content to populate mongodb collection

I am getting these two errors:

In VS code console:

```
API resolved without sending a response for /api/upload, this may result in stalled requests.
```

and in web app:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {storageErrors}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Call Stack
throwOnInvalidObjectType
node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (14887:0)
createChild
node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (15139:0)
reconcileChildrenArray
node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (15404:0)
reconcileChildFibers
node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (15821:0)
reconcileChildren
node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (19167:0)
updateHostComponent
node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (19924:0)
beginWork
node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (21618:0)
HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback
node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (4164:0)
Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev
node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (4213:0)
invokeGuardedCallback
node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (4277:0)
beginWork$1
node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (27451:0)
performUnitOfWork
node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (26557:0)
workLoopSync
node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (26466:0)
renderRootSync
node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (26434:0)
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot
node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom.development.js (25738:0)
workLoop
node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js (266:0)
flushWork
node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js (239:0)
MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline
node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js (533:0)
```

This is my code for the frontend and API in Nextjs:

**Frontend**

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const IndexPage = () => {
  const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState(null);
  const [uploading, setUploading] = useState(false);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const handleFileChange = (event) => {
    setSelectedFile(event.target.files[0]);
  };

  const handleFileUpload = async () => {
    if (!selectedFile) {
      setError('Please select a file');
      return;
    }

    setError(null);
    setMessage(null);
    setUploading(true);

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', selectedFile);

    try {
      const response = await fetch('/api/upload', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData,
      });

      const data = await response.json();

      if (response.ok) {
        setMessage(data.message);
      } else {
        setError(data.error);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      setError('Something went wrong');
    } finally {
      setUploading(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>File Upload</h1>

      <input
        name="file"
        type="file"
        accept=".csv"
        onChange={handleFileChange}
      />

      <button
        onClick={handleFileUpload}
        disabled={uploading}
      >
        {uploading ? 'Uploading...' : 'Upload'}
      </button>

      {message && <p>{message}</p>}
      {error && <p>Error: {error}</p>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default IndexPage;
```

**This is the Backend**

```
// pages/api/upload.js

import multer from 'multer';
import csv from 'csv-parser';
import fs from 'fs';
import { MongoClient, ObjectId } from 'mongodb';

const upload = multer({
  dest: 'uploads/', // Directory to store uploaded files
  limits: {
    fileSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024, // Limit file size to 5MB
  },
  fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
    if (file.mimetype !== 'text/csv') {
      cb(new Error('Only CSV files are allowed'));
    } else {
      cb(null, true);
    }
  },
});

const saveDistinctValues = async (collectionName, distinctValues) => {
  const client = new MongoClient('mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017/testcsv');
  try {
    await client.connect();
    const db = client.db();
    const collection = db.collection(collectionName);
    await collection.insertMany(distinctValues.map((value) => ({ value })));
  } finally {
    await client.close();
  }
};

const establishRelationships = async () => {
  const client = new MongoClient(process.env.MONGODB_URI);
  try {
    await client.connect();
    const db = client.db();
    const masterCategoryCollection = db.collection('master_category');
    const subCategoryCollection = db.collection('sub_category');
    const productGroupCollection = db.collection('product_group');
    const productCollection = db.collection('product');

    const masterCategories = await masterCategoryCollection.find().toArray();

    for (let i = 0; i < masterCategories.length; i++) {
      const masterCategory = masterCategories[i];
      const subCategory = await subCategoryCollection.findOne({
        value: masterCategory.value,
      });

      const productGroup = await productGroupCollection.findOne({
        value: subCategory.value,
      });

      const products = await productCollection
        .find({
          subCategoryId: { $exists: false },
          masterCategoryId: masterCategory._id,
        })
        .toArray();

      for (let j = 0; j < products.length; j++) {
        const product = products[j];
        await productCollection.updateOne(
          { _id: product._id },
          {
            $set: {
              subCategoryId: subCategory._id,
              productGroupId: productGroup._id,
            },
          }
        );
      }
    }
  } finally {
    await client.close();
  }
};

const handler = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await upload.single('file')(req, res, async (error) => {
      if (error instanceof multer.MulterError) {
        // Multer error occurred during file upload
        res.status(400).json({ error: error.message });
      } else if (error) {
        // Other errors occurred
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Something went wrong', error });
      } else if (!req.file) {
        // No file was provided
        res.status(400).json({ error: 'No file uploaded' });
      } else {
        const filePath = req.file.path;
        const masterCategories = [];
        const subCategories = [];
        const productGroups = [];
        const products = [];

        fs.createReadStream(filePath)
          .pipe(csv())
          .on('data', (row) => {
            const masterCategory = row.master_category.trim();
            const subCategory = row.sub_category.trim();
            const productGroup = row.product_group.trim();
            const product = row.product.trim();

            if (masterCategory !== '') {
              masterCategories.push({ value: masterCategory });
            }
            if (subCategory !== '') {
              subCategories.push({ value: subCategory });
            }
            if (productGroup !== '') {
              productGroups.push({ value: productGroup });
            }
            if (product !== '') {
              products.push({ value: product });
            }
          })
          .on('end', async () => {
            // Save distinct values to collections
            await saveDistinctValues('master_category', masterCategories);
            await saveDistinctValues('sub_category', subCategories);
            await saveDistinctValues('product_group', productGroups);
            await saveDistinctValues('product', products);

            // Establish relationships between collections
            await establishRelationships();

            res
              .status(200)
              .json({ message: 'File uploaded and processed successfully' });
          })
          .on('error', (error) => {
            console.error('Error processing CSV:', error.message);
            res.status(500).json({ error: 'Something went wrong' });
          });
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error uploading file:', error.message);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Something went wrong' });
  }
};

export default handler;
```

I am unable to understand this error as I am new to Next and React. I have looked around and I believe that the problem is with the way I am using the components!

Comment: Either your error or message state seems to be an object. You cannot render an object. The error in your console is related to this [issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/40270#discussioncomment-3571223).

Answer (score 0):

You have this error because you are trying to display your error which is an `Object`.

In this scenario you would either check what error you got from the backend and show a error message related. (Where you have `setError(data.error);`)

Or

For testing purposes, you can simply display the error as it is, as an object, this way:

```
{error && <p>Error: {JSON.stringify(error)}</p>}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your React app is erroring because the `error` value you're trying to display is an object - you can't put an object directly into the JSX.

`error` being an object is probably coming from this line, where you've used the key `error` twice, the second instance overriding the first with the `Error` object.

```
 else if (error) {
    // Other errors occurred
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Something went wrong', error });
```

Comment: I removed that error, I had put it in to see what was going on but I guess I was wrong. When I remove it I get this:

API resolved without sending a response for /api/upload, this may result in stalled requests.

Comment: I am hitting this error in the API file:
res.status(500).json({ error: 'Something went wrong', error });

Comment: You need to see what the error is. Add `console.error(error)` to your server code, or you can keep the original code and stringify the error so you can render it in JSX. `<pre>{JSON.stringify(error, null, 2)}</pre>`